# Do while loop ending my program

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have problem with a do while loop. When I execute the program, first it goes through the menu then, then execute the code, but then it ends the program.

```
public class Draft {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
static Holding[]holding = new Holding[15];
static int hold = 0;
private static Scanner scanner;
public static void main(String[] args){
    int options;
    do{ 
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i <=50; i++){
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Library Management System");

        for(int i = 0; i <=50; i++){
            System.out.print("=");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("1. Add Holding");
        System.out.println("2. Remove Holding");
        System.out.println("3. Exit);


        options = scanner.nextInt();
        switch(options){

        case 1:
            addHolding();
            break;
        case 2:
            removeHolding();
        default:
            System.out.println("Please");
        }

    }while(options == 3);
    System.out.println("I'm out");

public void addHolding(){
int option = input.nextInt();
switch(option)

case 1:
addBook();
break;
case 2:
addVideo();
break;
default:
System.out.println("Please select the following option");


public static void addBook{
(execute code)
}
```

So after executing the addBook method, It ends the program. My question is

**What do I need to fix for my code go back to the menu instead of ending my program**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your program to end if you enter 3 I assume?

If yes: You keep your loop running if you pressed 'Exit'.

You want your loop to run `while(option != 3);`. While it isn't 3, continue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
        ***while(options == 3)***
use
        ***while(options != 3);***